# How to make my computer turn on automatically

Tags: boot, shutdown, automatic

I want to make my computer to turn back on automatically when it is powered off by some reason. Is this possible ?

Comment: Make and model of computer?  What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a BIOS setting but one I've only really noticed on higher-end motherboards. Fish around in the advanced and power settings and look for items with "AC" in the title. Here's a [Tom's Hardware Article on the power settings](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bios-beginners,1126-8.html) which includes such an option, called "AC Power Loss Restart" here... But the exact name *does* vary.

If you can't find or don't have a setting like that your alternative is better but more expensive: a UPS. Essentially a big 12V battery that you plug your computer in to. It'll handle surges and should keep the computer running for a period of time (determined by the size of the battery). Getting the battery size correct is important (too much load on a small battery can fry the UPS) but 1000VA is a good start for the average destkop.

I don't think there's a pure-software solution to this. My next alternative involved a Lego Mindstorm robot that presses your power (and then Escape) button on a schedule... But now we're getting weird.

Comment: Nice. I will try with the software solution and if my server go well then I will buy UPS.